# Nexus 7 came with Superuser & ROM Manager pre-installed

Tags: nexus-7, root-access

I just received my Nexus 7 from Google and I was surprised to see superuser and ROM Manager apps already installed. How normal is this? Does this mean my tablet is rooted out of the box? Does it mean it was used before? Does it void the warranty?

Answer (score 1):

Did you purchased it directly from Google? Very likely you simply got a returned tablet, i.e. a tablet that already had a previous owner, which installed these apps. I doubt that Google pre-installs SuperUser and ROM Manager.

Comment: Actually I won it on the Kit Kat promotion. Yet it came with the precinct and all.

Comment: Still, it seems that somebody used it before :)